# Service.Redis Trimming a list

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

Following tutorials that is using ServiceStack v3 and stuck at when trying to trim a list in V4.

What is the equivalent in V4? Trying to google examples but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [TrimList](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs#L207), e.g:

```
redis.TrimList(listId, keepStartingFrom, keepEndingAt);
```

Or you can use [Trim() off IList](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisList.cs#L26), e.g:

```
redis.Lists[listId].Trim(keepStartingFrom, keepEndingAt);
```

Both [TrimList()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/Generic/IRedisTypedClient.cs#L119) and [IRedisList.Trim()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/Generic/IRedisList.Generic.cs#L30) also have Redis Typed Client API versions:

```
redis.As<Poco>().TrimList(listId, keepStartingFrom, keepEndingAt);
redis.As<Poco>().Lists[listId].Trim(keepStartingFrom, keepEndingAt);
```